# PHP - where is the array?

Tags: php

This code is supposed to work. My opinion :)
The problem is that I gat this error:

> PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array

Why $row is not an array?

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);
$csvarray = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $csvarray[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

$head = $csvarray[0];
unset($csvarray[0]);
$all_rows= array();

$n=0;
while ($row = $csvarray != false) {

    if($n>100) break;
        $n++;
        $all_rows[] = array_combine($head, $row);
    }
    print_r($all_rows);
```

Comment: `print_r($row)` __and see__. This obviously should be done __before__ asking the question.

Comment: As `$csvarray != false` equals to `true`, `$row` is __`true`__.

Comment: Because `$csvarray != false` returns a boolean NOT an array:)

Comment: Ok, a typographical error.

Comment: FYI, if any of the values in your CSV might ever contain a line break, `$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);` will mess things up anyway.

Comment: maybe problem is that $row at the end has an empty array. Can this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Because in PHP, assignment goes from right-to-left and comparison operator `!=` [takes precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) over assignment operator `=`, which results in `$row` being `false`.

```
$csvarray = [];
var_dump($row = $csvarray != false); // bool(false)
var_dump($row); // bool(false)
var_dump($csvarray ); // array(0) { }
```

This happens because the expression `$csvarray != false` takes precedence (*it happens first*) over the assignment and results in `false`. Then assignment happens making `$row == false`. To change precedence use parens `()` around the expression you want to happen first. So `($row = $csvarray) != false`.

```
/* Notice the difference */
$csvarray = [];
var_dump(($row = $csvarray) != false); // bool(false)
var_dump($row); // array(0) { }
var_dump($csvarray ); // array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

`!=` has a higher precedence than `=` - so what you have written, is effectively  the same as

```
$row = ($csvarray != false)
```

The result of that comparison is either true or false, and *that* is what then gets assigned to $row.

Comment: And as a solution `foreach ($csvarray as $row)` can be used.

Comment: Solved! while is not working. Foreach OK! Thank you